# Lenovo Thinkpad Unknown Password

Tags: lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, disk-encryption, password-recovery

[image: A photograph of the password prompt]

A Lenovo ThinkPad has an unexplained password prompt that appears after POST. 
Even when I go to the BIOS I still have to go through this password. 
I have tried turning all passwords I could find in the BIOS but it won't turn off. 
What password is this and how do you turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a HDD password, as one can tell by the icon next to the lock. Information on how to change / remove it, can be found [here](https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/solutions/ht036206).